# onChange for dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a dropdown list that, when an option is select, should dynamically display a div section. Unfortunately, the code i have researched and tried isn't working.

CSS:

```
body {
        background-image: url(http://fjordstudio.dk/assets/img/bg/diamonds.png);
        color: white;
    }
    #container {
        background-color: grey;
        border: solid thick black;
        border-radius: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 40%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #complaintDrop {
        display: None;
    }
```

Here's part of my code: HTML

```
<form name = "form1" method = "post" id = "complaintForm">
<div id = "container">
    <div id = "drop1">
        <p>
          <label>Please Select your reason for contacting us.
            <select name="contactType" id="contactType" onchange = "complaining()">
              <option value="C" id = "empty">Select a Reason</option>
              <option value="C" id = "complaints">Complaints</option>
              <option value="T" id = "technicalPr">Technical Problems</option>
              <option value="P" id = "productIss">Product Issues</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </p>
    </div><!--end of drop-->
    <!--<ol>
      <li>When  Complaints are selected please dynamically create and display a new drop down list that includes at least four options of your choice.</li>
      <li>When Technical Problems are selected please dynamically create and display at least four types of problems with an associated checkbox.</li>
      <li>When Product Issues aer selected please dynamically create and display at least four types options as a grouped set of radio buttons. </li>
      <li>When a new option is selected your script should remove any of the dynamic content. </li>
    </ol>-->
    <div id = "complaintDrop">
        <p>Select a Complaint:
            <select name = "complaints" id = "complaints1">
                <option value = "load">App Takes too Long to Load</option>
                <option value = "colors">Poor Color Design</option>
                <option value = "fit">Some Content Does Not Show</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div><!--end of complaintDrop-->
```

Javascript(jQuery):

```
<script src = "jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

$(document).ready(function(e) {

function complaining() {
        $("#complaintDrop").css("display", "block");
    }

}
</script>
```

Entire Document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>WDV321 Advanced Javascript</title>

<!--Name: Robin Jennings
    Date: 10/2/2017
    Project: Dynamic Form Structure-->

<style>
    body {
        background-image: url(http://fjordstudio.dk/assets/img/bg/diamonds.png);
        color: white;
    }
    #container {
        background-color: grey;
        border: solid thick black;
        border-radius: 45px;
        text-align: center;
        width: 40%;
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    #complaintDrop {
        display: None;
    }
    #techProblem {
        display: none;
    }
    #prIssues {
        display: none;
    }
</style>

<script src = "jquery-3.2.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

function complaining() {
    if( $("#drop1").val() == $("#complaints").val());
        $("#complaintDrop").css("display", "block");
        $("#techProblem").css("display", "none");
        $("#prIssues").css("display", "none");
}
</script>

</head>

<body>

<h2 style = "text-align: center;">Dynamic Form Structure - Assignment</h2>
<!--<p>Use this page as the basis for your assignment. Given the drop down list provided on this page please do the following things.</p>-->
<form name = "form1" method = "post" id = "complaintForm">
<div id = "container">
    <div id = "drop1">
        <p>
          <label>Please Select your reason for contacting us.
            <select name="contactType" id="contactType" onchange = "complaining()">
              <option value="S" id = "empty" name = "empty">Select a Reason</option>
              <option value="C" id = "complaints" id = "complaints">Complaints</option>
              <option value="T" id = "technicalPr" name = "technicalPr">Technical Problems</option>
              <option value="P" id = "productIss" name = "productIss">Product Issues</option>
            </select>
          </label>
        </p>
    </div><!--end of drop-->
    <!--<ol>
      <li>When  Complaints are selected please dynamically create and display a new drop down list that includes at least four options of your choice.</li>
      <li>When Technical Problems are selected please dynamically create and display at least four types of problems with an associated checkbox.</li>
      <li>When Product Issues aer selected please dynamically create and display at least four types options as a grouped set of radio buttons. </li>
      <li>When a new option is selected your script should remove any of the dynamic content. </li>
    </ol>-->
    <div id = "complaintDrop">
        <p>Select a Complaint:
            <select name = "complaints" id = "complaints1">
                <option value = "load">App Takes too Long to Load</option>
                <option value = "colors">Poor Color Design</option>
                <option value = "fit">Some Content Does Not Show</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div><!--end of complaintDrop-->
    <div id = "techProblem">
        <label for = "technical problems">Technical Problems:<br><br>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "techPr" value = "Poor User Experience">Poor User Experience<br>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "techPr" value = "App Force Closes">App Force Closes<br>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "techPr" value = "Does Not Save My Changes">Does Not Save My Changes<br>
            <input type = "checkbox" name = "techPr" value = "Poor Graphics Quality">Poor Graphics Quality<br><br><br>
        </label>
    </div><!--End of techProblems-->
    <div id = "prIssues">
        <label for = "Product Issues">Product Issues:
            <p>Software Got Lost During Delivery
                <input type = "radio" name = "prIss" value = "Software Got Lost During Delivery">
            </p>
            <p>Software Was Delivered Late
                <input type = "radio" name = "prIss" value = "Software Was Delivered Late">
            </p>
            <p>Software Was Damaged Upon Delivery
                <input type = "radio" name = "prIss" value = "Software Was Damaged Upon Delivery">
            </p>
            <p>Software Does Not Install
                <input type = "radio" name = "prIss" value = "Software Does Not Install">
            </p>
        </label>
    </div><!--end of prIssues-->
        <input type = "button" name = "submit" value = "Submit">
        <input type = "reset" name = "reset" value = "reset">
</div><!--end of container-->
</form>

<p>&nbsp;</p>

</body>
</html>
```

The div for complaintDrop is hidden via CSS. When I select "Complaints" from the dropdown list, I want the complaintDrop div to display. But alas, it remains hidden. I have plenty of practice with the onClick events, but not so much for onChange. Which is what I believe I need to use here. Any help would be great. Thank you.

Comment: do you see errors in your developer tools console? note: function `complaining` isn't in the global scope ... that definition does NOT need to be in document.ready (which will fix the scope issue)

Comment: or add `$("#complaintDrop").on('change', complaining)` inside *document.ready* **instead of** your `onchange = "complaining()"` attribute ... `on*` attributes are rarely useful ... adding event listeners programatically are usually the way to go

Comment: @Jaromanda X, Taking out the document.ready seems to do the trick. Thank you!

Comment: @Jaromanda X, That worked, but only to display the first div. I have two more divs that need dynamically displayed from the other two options in the dropdown.

Comment: not sure, because you've only shown two, and only one has an onchange attribute ... so, I could only guess

Comment: "here's" ... where?

Comment: @Jaromanda X, I have two more divs. Total amount of divs: 3. Names: #complaintDrop, #techProblem, #prIssues. From the drop down, you have helped me to display #complaintDrop. But I need to display the other divs by selecting a new choice, while hiding divs not associated with the selection from the dropdown. <option id = "complaints"> displays #complaintDrop. <option id = "technicalPr"> displays #techProblem. <option id = "productIss"> displays #prIssues. So far We have gotten only #complaintDrop to display.

Comment: @Jaromanda X, I also updated my original question to show my entire document.